# MYSQL - libmysql.dll error

Tags: php, mysql

I have just installed MySQL on windows server 2003 32-bit.
I have PHP 5.2.6.

When doing in cmd: `php -m` to get the modules I have this error:

```
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'libmySQL.dll"
in Unknown on line 0"
```

the dll in located in:

```
"C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\libmySQL"
```

My `php.ini` looks like this:

```
extension=libmySQL.dll
```

I tried to download again the DLL and restart the server, still the same error.
I have this DLL in `system32` as well, can you please help me?

Comment: what is your extension_dir value

Comment: extension_dir ="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"

Comment: is the complete path like C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\libmySQL.dll or C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\libmySQL\libmySQL.dll ?

Comment: the dll is located at: "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext" the path in the php.ini is: C:\Program Files\PHP\ext

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded the 32-bit version of the dll and not the 64-bit one.

Comment: Done, still not working,

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

All builtin PHP extension files start with `php_...`, not `lib`. Particularly, the legacy deprecated MySQL extension is loaded this way:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

I'd say you're attempting to load something that's not a PHP extension at all (it looks like the MySQL library used by MySQL clients like Workbench or HeidiSQL).